# Claim not found despite being sent in the SAML assertion

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-application-insights

According to the trace in Application Insights, I'm missing the `givenName` claim. The exception message is:

```
""Message"": ""A Claim of ClaimType with id \""givenName\"" was not found, which is required by the ClaimsTransformationImpl of Type \""Microsoft.Cpim.Data.Transformations.StringReplaceTransformation\"" for TransformationMethod \""StringReplace\"" referenced by the ClaimsTransformation with id \""NormalizeGivenNameMeijburg\"" in policy \""B2C_1A_MeijburgExtension\"" of tenant \""isideb2cdev.onmicrosoft.com\""."",
```

What's really confusing though is that earlier in the trace, I can see the SAML assertion, and it definitely has that claim. See a snippet below (I wasn't sure if it contained sensitive info, so I left a lot of the assertion out here):

```
<saml:Attribute Name=\""givenname\""><saml:AttributeValue>Redmar</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute><saml:Attribute Name=\""surname\""><saml:AttributeValue>de Vries</saml:AttributeValue></saml:Attribute>
```

In my RP file, I have the following in the `TechnicalProfile` tag:

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="Policy Profile">
    <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="Meijburg.com" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaims>
    <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
</TechnicalProfile>
```

In the extension file, I have the following in `OutputClaims` tag:

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="Meijburg.com" />
</OutputClaims>
```

The client's metadata has the following in the `ClaimTypesOffered` tag:

```
<fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Name</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>The mutable display name of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Subject</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>An immutable, globally unique, non-reusable identifier of the user that is unique to the application for which a token is issued.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Given Name</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>First name of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/surname" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Surname</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Last name of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/displayname" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Display Name</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Display name of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/nickname" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Nick Name</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Nick name of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationinstant" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Authentication Instant</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>The time (UTC) when the user is authenticated to Windows Azure Active Directory.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Authentication Method</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>The method that Windows Azure Active Directory uses to authenticate users.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>ObjectIdentifier</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Primary identifier for the user in the directory. Immutable, globally unique, non-reusable.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/tenantid" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>TenantId</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Identifier for the user's tenant.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/identityprovider" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>IdentityProvider</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Identity provider for the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Email</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Email address of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/groups" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Groups</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Groups of the user.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/accesstoken" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>External Access Token</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Access token issued by external identity provider</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/expiration" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>External Access Token Expiration</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>UTC expiration time of access token issued by external identity provider.</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/openid2_id" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>External OpenID 2.0 Identifier</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>OpenID 2.0 identifier issued by external identity provider</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/claims/groups.link" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>GroupsOverageClaim</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Issued when number of user's group claims exceeds return limit</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>Role Claim</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Roles that the user or Service Principal is attached to</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
    <auth:ClaimType Uri="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/wids" xmlns:auth="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wsfed/authorization/200706">
        <auth:DisplayName>RoleTemplate Id Claim</auth:DisplayName>
        <auth:Description>Role template id of the Built-in Directory Roles that the user is a member of</auth:Description>
    </auth:ClaimType>
</fed:ClaimTypesOffered>
```

I'm failing to see where I'm going wrong here. One interesting tidbit...Currently the first ClaimsTransformation that runs runs on givenName. However, if I change the first one to run on surname, the claim says that that Claims Transformation is missing the claim `surname`. How can I get the claims to go through like they're supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This required Microsoft support, but their fix was to change the OutputClaims to use the shorthand versions of PartnerClaimType. So that section should look like this:

```
<OutputClaims>
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" PartnerClaimType="assertionSubjectName" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="givenname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" PartnerClaimType="surname" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" PartnerClaimType="emailaddress" />
    <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" DefaultValue="Meijburg.com" />
</OutputClaims>
```

They claim that, in general, you can replace the full uri in PartnerClaimType with the shorthand, but that hasn't worked in other implementations, so I'm considering this a one-off fix.

Answer (score 0):

The mapping is already defined in the claim:

```
<ClaimType Id="displayName">
                <DisplayName>Display Name</DisplayName>
                <DataType>string</DataType>
                <DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                    <Protocol Name="OAuth2" PartnerClaimType="unique_name"/>
                    <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" PartnerClaimType="name"/>
                    <Protocol Name="SAML2" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name"/>
                </DefaultPartnerClaimTypes>
                <UserHelpText>Your display name.</UserHelpText>
                <UserInputType>TextBox</UserInputType>
            </ClaimType>
```

I don't have any mappings of the type:

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" PartnerClaimType="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname" />
```

Also, in the RP:

```
<Protocol Name="SAML2"/>
```

and in the user journey:

```
<!-- SAML issuer technical profile -->
                <OrchestrationStep Order="12" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="Saml2AssertionIssuer"/>
```

Comment: Ok, so a few things. Changing the RP protocol and adding the user journey in the base policy won't fix this because, even though the IdP uses SAML2, the application we send the data to uses OpenIdConnect. It's worth mentioning that we have this exact scheme working on a different tenant too. 

Regarding the first 2 comments, there is 100% a ClaimType in the base policy with the Id `givenName`, which has a corresponding mapping in the client's metadata, so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you don't have a mapping for `givenName`.